# Performing search across multiple tables using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to perform a search action on my page. I have 3 tables on my database with no relation between then. I created a view model called SearchModel and I'm trying to send the query data to the view like below

I'm very new to ASP.NET*

```
IQueryable<SearchModel> t = Enumerable.Empty<SearchModel>().AsQueryable();

var searchD = from d in db.domains
              where d.domainName.Contains(search) //search is the search string
              select d;
var searchU = from u in db.users
              where u.userName.Contains(search)
              select u;
var searchA = from a in db.adminLists
              where a.userName.Contains(search)
              select a;
t.searchDomain = searchD;
t.searchAdmin = searchA;
t.searchUsers = searchU;
return view(t);
```

I get an error saying this

```
IQueryable<SearchModel>' does not contain a definition for 'searchDomain'
and no accessible extension method 'searchDomain' accepting a first argument of type
'IQueryable<SearchModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is my view model

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public user searchUsers { get; set; }
    public adminList searchAdmin { get; set; }
    public domain searchDomain { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing and/or is there a better way to implement the search?

Comment: Use the inner join in your linq query rather than declaring variable again.

Comment: Could you clarify further?

Comment: Clarifying further on @Khizar comment....           
From t1 in db.Table1
join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.field equals t2.field
select new { t1.field2, t2.field3}

Comment: @Bosco well that is the issue here. My tables are have no relation so performing a join will return nothing

Comment: Try using a list instead of IQueryable

Comment: @AashishShrestha kindly post your view here as well